# Excel error - formula contains SUMIFS, and OR and Some Dates

Tags: excel

I'm trying to get the formula below to work but I'm getting a `#Spill!` error

Adding Feb-20 works fine but adding the Mar-20 appears to break something.

```
=SUMIFS(Calcs!CZ:CZ,Calcs!$AL:$AL,{"Feb-20","Mar-20"},Calcs!$AJ:$AJ,"<>"&"")
```

Comment: Wrap it in sumproduct

Comment: Thanks Scott! Unfortunately this did not give the correct answer but at least I got an answer! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that due to the later additions into excel, the modern interpretation of array criteria is that for each of your criteria, it produces an array of answers, so you are getting #Spill! because excel is trying to make your single celled sumifs formula spill into two cells, each using a single criteria of your array criteria:

one cell having this formula in:

```
=SUMIFS(Calcs!CZ:CZ,Calcs!$AL:$AL,"Feb-20",Calcs!$AJ:$AJ,"<>"&"")
```

and the other cell having this formula in:

```
=SUMIFS(Calcs!CZ:CZ,Calcs!$AL:$AL,"Mar-20",Calcs!$AJ:$AJ,"<>"&"")
```

The spill error is likely because the cell adjacent to the cell you are performing this sumifs formula in has something in it.

documentation on this here:

https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/dynamic-array-formulas-spill-ranges/

My suggestion therefore is to simply wrap your current formula with a final sum, like this:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Calcs!CZ:CZ,Calcs!$AL:$AL,{"Feb-20","Mar-20"},Calcs!$AJ:$AJ,"<>"&""))
```

Comment: Hi John thank you so much. Your answer makes sense and is in line with the error 'floatie' indicating the adjacent cell. I managed to find a workaround for now will dig back in when I have more time! Thanks again for the thoughtful and detailed answer!